# Jackson JSON : Subclass fields not seralized if implements java.util.Set

Tags: java, jackson

I have following inheritance

```
interface ResultSet extends java.util.Set<CustomResult> {
    public int getCount();
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "CustomResultSet")
class CustomResultSet extends LinkedHashSet<CustomResult> implements ResultSet {

    @XmlElement(name = "count")
    private int count;

    public void setCount(int count) {
       this.count = count
    }

}
.
.
public static void main() {
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
CustomResultSet customResultSet = new CustomResultSet();
CustomResult customResult = new CustomResult(55, "abc");
customResultSet.setCount(11);
customResultSet.add(CustomResult);
System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(customResultSet));

}
```

With above code serializes values in collection CustomResultSet but not field count in CustomResultSet .

Comment: 1) Your code does not compile 2) You don't set a value for the `count` property on your `CustomResultSet`, so why do you expect JSON to be output for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that implements the `Set` interface is treated as a Set by Jackson and it will result in a JSON array, even if you put annotations on your custom class. Your best shot is to have a custom serializer for your class.